# Internal rotation in dips?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding, dips

Here's a picture of athleanx demonstrating dips https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMyFe-IL7Ks

[image]

I understand the forward lean is required in dips, but doesn't this make the exercise extremely susceptible to  internal rotation? What's the mechanics of it all?

Comment: What forward lean? His torso is almost completely upright. Also, what do you mean by "internal rotation"? His shoulders are externally rotated in this photo.